# Is there a way to minimize class definitions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class

I want to use classes in my Node Application but I wonder whether there is a way (like in typescript) to minimize class definitions, for example:

```
class Rectangle(

    constructor(height, width){
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
)
```

to something like

```
class Rectangle(

    constructor(height, width){}
)
```

so I do not need to assign the values from the constructor to variables with exactly the same name.

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is no; that's a feature of TypeScript only.

Comment: @KenY-N Thank you for the information. I read that you can use TypeScript classes in Node applications - I may try to work with TS classes in my Node application if that should not be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) are a typescript only feature. As you can see in this example on [ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQYwNghgzlwEoFMQBcIDsDmYEG8BQwhRhIA9mlMgE4CuKpVAFAA5UCWAbhMgsABYI2GPsgBcaGgFsARgioAaYMxrSwbEMADubACbI%204qbKoBKHMAC%20BC0A), a class like

```
class Rectangle{
   constructor(private height:number, public width:number){ }
}
```

gets transpiled into:

```
"use strict";
class Rectangle {
    constructor(height, width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
}
```

You can, however, just use TypeScript in your NodeJS app - given that you set up a build-step where you transpile/compile your typescript code into javascript. Alternatively you can use a library like [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) to run your code.